# Matplotlib - Clear Old figure from canvas after savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

Matplotlib version - 1.53

Backend - qt4agg

I've implemented copy to clipboard functionality using the following code.

```
    fig = self.canvas.figure
    fig.set_size_inches(width,height)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf,dpi=300,transparent=True,bbox_inches='tight')
    image=QtGui.QImage.fromData(buf.getvalue())
    mimeData = QMimeData()
    mimeData.setData("PNG",buf.getvalue())
    QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().setMimeData(mimeData)
    buf.close()
```

I'm taking figure width and height as user input.

Canvas
[image: Canvas]

After Ctrl+C

[image: After Ctrl+C]

Now the figure (with user input height/width) copied is displayed on top of the original image. This overlay-ed figure is helpful as any overlapping legend,annotation etc. can be dragged based on the copied figure size. So it is kind of a print preview. (Not implemented by me - came automatically)

The image gets copied to clipboard perfectly. My only problem here is the underlying figure (aesthetics) . Zoom/pan etc works only with the overlay-ed figure and has no effect on the underlying figure. Is there any way to clear the underlying figure only.

Resizing the window removes the overlay-ed figure and restores control to underlying figure.

Sample Code:

```
import io
from PyQt4.uic import loadUiType
from PyQt4.QtCore import QMimeData

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
        FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
        NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('window.ui')


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, ):
                super(Main, self).__init__()
                self.setupUi(self)
                self.fig_dict = {}

                self.mplfigs.itemClicked.connect(self.changefig)
                self.menu()
                fig = Figure()
                self.addmpl(fig)
        def menu(self):
            copyimg=QtGui.QAction('&Copy', self) 
            copyimg.setShortcut('Ctrl+C')
            copyimg.setStatusTip('Copy to Clipboard')
            copyimg.triggered.connect(self.copy_to_clipboard)
            menubar = self.menuBar()
            fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Edit')
            fileMenu.addAction(copyimg)

        def copy_to_clipboard(self):
            fig = self.canvas.figure
            fig.set_size_inches(6,4)
            buf = io.BytesIO()
            fig.savefig(buf,dpi=300,transparent=True,bbox_inches='tight')
            image=QtGui.QImage.fromData(buf.getvalue())
            mimeData = QMimeData()
            mimeData.setData("PNG",buf.getvalue())
            QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().setMimeData(mimeData)
            buf.close()

        def changefig(self, item):
                text = item.text()
                text = str(text)
                self.rmmpl()
                self.addmpl(self.fig_dict[text])


        def addfig(self, name, fig):
                self.fig_dict[name] = fig
                self.mplfigs.addItem(name)

        def addmpl(self, fig):
                self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
                self.mplvl.addWidget(self.canvas)
                self.canvas.draw()
                self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, 
                                self.mplwindow, coordinates=True)
                self.mplvl.addWidget(self.toolbar)
                self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key_press)

        def on_key_press(self, event):
                key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, self.toolbar)

        def rmmpl(self,):
                self.mplvl.removeWidget(self.canvas)
                self.canvas.close()
                self.mplvl.removeWidget(self.toolbar)
                self.toolbar.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        from PyQt4 import QtGui
        import numpy as np

        fig1 = Figure()
        ax1f1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
        ax1f1.plot(np.random.rand(5))


        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        main = Main()
        main.addfig('One plot', fig1)
        main.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

window.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1280</width>
    <height>768</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="mplwindow" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="focusPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ClickFocus</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="mplvl"/>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QListWidget" name="mplfigs">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>200</width>
        <height>0</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>200</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="focusPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ClickFocus</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1280</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're using the fact that the figure canvas is not yet repainted such that the part of the window that does not need to host the new (smaller) figure is not repainted and still shows the old graphics. What is shown in the background is thus not more than some lines and letters and there is no relation to any existing python object that you could use to manipulate the background.

Comment: Yes it is aesthetics related issue only. But is it possible to clear the old graphics before painting the new(smaller) figure?

Comment: There probably is some way, but it would be good to have a [mcve] of the issue as I currently cannot reproduce it. The matplotlib window simply resizes itself when `fig.set_size_inches` is called and I don't know how you implemented it into the QtGui, i.e. you might have used some window flags or layout managers.

Comment: updated post with example and ui file.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest any luck?

Comment: The only option I see at the moment is to get the original figuresize back, e.g. by adding  `self.resize(self.frameGeometry().width(), self.frameGeometry().height())` at the end of the `copy_to_clipboard` function. But that lets you loose the "print preview".